# Mixed model with large sample size

Tags: r, models, mixed

I am currently doing a mixed linear model (using the `lme` function in R), and I have some problems.

My dataset is about damages by brown bears in Slovenia. Slovenia was divided in 1x1km grids, and for each grid I have data of number of damages per year (for 12 consecutive years). This frequency of damages will be my `Y` variable in the model, and I will test different environmental variables to explain occurrence of damages (e.g. distance to the forest edge, cover of forest etc.). 
I put year as a random factor (verified with a likelihood ratio test).

My sample size is big (250 000 cell values), and mainly 0 (only 4000 cases were positive, ranging from 1 to 17 damages in one cell for a year).

Here is my problem. Following Zuur (2009) methods, I try to find the optimal fixed structure for my model. My first model has all the variables, plus some interactions (see below). I'm using a logit link.

```
f1 <- formula (dam ~ masting + dens*pop_size_index + saturation + exposition
 settlements + orchards + crops + meadows + mixed_for + dist_for_out
 dist_for_out_a + dist_for_in + dist_for_in_a + for_edge + prop_broadleaves
 prop_broadleaves_a + dist_road + dist_village + feed_stat + sup_food 
 masting*prop_broadleaves)    
M1.lme <- lme (f1, random = ~1|year, method="REML", data=d)
```

But, looking at likelihood ratio test, I can not remove ANY variable. All are significant. However, the model is still very bad (too many variables in, residuals not good looking), and I can definitely not stop there.

So how can I find a better model (i.e. get rid of non significant variables)?

Is this due to my large sample size? 
Could this zero inflation possibly be a problem?

I could not find another way of improving my model, that would take this into account.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Some comments: You should account for spatial (and possibly temporal) auto-correlation. Also, it is unclear how you are dealing with your zero-inflated Poisson data. You don't say which family you use. Collinearity should also be investigated.

Comment: I would recommend using the `stepAIC` function in the `MASS` package which supports forward, backward and stepwise variable selection based on either AIC, BIC or loglikelihood based criterion with a `k` penalization of your choice.

Comment: This is less a coding question and more a statistical advice request. (I have no idea what it means to say that the choice to put year in as a random factor could be verified by a LR.) Suggest migration to CV.